# How do I replace content or keyword of an xml (like applicationContext.xml) with Gradle build?

Tags: gradle, replace, ant, build.gradle, applicationcontext

My application has applicationContext.xml with entityManagerFactory bean defined as :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="packagesToScan" value="org.xyz" />
**<property name="dataSource" ref="poolDVLDataSource" />**  
<!--<property name="dataSource" ref="poolPRDDataSource" /> -->  
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" 
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
  </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

and data source references as

```
 <bean id="poolPRDDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
 ....
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="poolDVLDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  ....
 </bean>
```

I'm using gradle for build.  Depending on the deploying environment, is there a way to replace the dataSource ref to either "poolDVLDataSource" or "poolPRDDataSource" dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceRegExp ant task should fix your issue. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html

Sample gradle code below:

```
ant.replaceregexp(match:'existingName', replace:'newName', byline:true) {
    fileset(dir: 'WebContent/WEB-INF', includes: 'applicationContext.xml')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be solving this with gradle, you should solve this in spring

You can use spring's `<import />` with a `${parameter}` so that the actual file is decided at runtime. For instance you could split your service configuration into two files. The "internal" file could contain all the services implemented by your application and the "external" config file could contain external config including database connections, JMS connections, mail servers etc, etc.

Eg: applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder/>
<import resource="classpath:internal-services.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:${environment}/external-services.xml" />
```

For production, you can pass `environment=prod` as a system property and load the `prod/external-services.xml` which contains the "real" services. For tests you could pass `environment=mock` and load `mock/external-services.xml` which contains mocks of all of your external services.